# Total in Function Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create a function `function examineNumbers()`. This function is supposed to prompt the user for numbers on the click of a button. The code is supposed to determine the `type` of the number as even, odd and float. Then add up all the sums `numTotal` and `floatTotal` and the averages `numAverage` and `floatAverage`. I actually have two issues. The while loop is not supposed to incorporate the `SENTINEL` into the code. It adds it in anytime `-1` is inputted by the user. It is just supposed to break the while loop.

Second issue is my code fails to add the total correctly. It shows the original value of 0 and displays all other numbers inputted next to the number 0 instead of adding into one sum. This occurs for `numTotal` and `floatTotal`. Can anyone help me determine where the issue is on these two items please?

```js
function examineNumbers() {

  const SENTINEL = -1;

  let number = 0;
  let type;
  let numValues = 0;
  let numAverage = 0;
  let floatValues = 0;
  let numTotal = 0;
  let floatTotal = 0;
  let list = document.getElementById("list");
  let numbers = document.getElementById("numbers");
  let floating = document.getElementById("floating");


  // while loop to only allow numbers greater than zero to be inputted
  while (number != SENTINEL) {
    number = prompt("Enter a number. Type " + SENTINEL + " to stop.");

    // deterrmines if a number is even
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
      type = " is an even value";
      numTotal += number;
      numValues++;
    }

    // determines if a number is odd
    else if (Math.abs(number % 2) == 1) {
      type = " is an odd value";
      numTotal += number;
      numValues++;
    }

    // gives a floating point type if above two aren't met
    else {
      type = " is a floating point value.";
      floatTotal += number;
      numTotal += number;
      numValues++;
      floatValues++;
    }

    let numResults;
    let floatResults;
    // averages non floating numbers
    numAverage = numTotal / numValues;
    numResults = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " The total is " + numTotal +
      " and the average is " + numAverage + ".";

    // gives value if  no non floating numbers are entered
    if (numValues == 0 && floatValues == 0) {
      numResults = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
    }

    // averages floating point numbers
    floatAverage = floatTotal / floatValues;
    floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = " The total is " + floatTotal +
      " and the average is " + floatAverage + ".";


    // gives value if no floating numbers are entered
    if (floatValues == 0) {
      floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = "No floating-pont values were entered."
    }


    let li = "";
    //only add number and its status to list when number not equal to SENTINEL
    if (number !== SENTINEL) {
      li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = number + type;
      list.appendChild(li);

      // displays information for both non floating numbers and floating numbers
      numbers.innerHTML = numResults;
      floating.innerHTML = floatResults;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> Number Examination Tool </h1>

<form name="myForm">

  <button type="button" onclick="examineNumbers();">Click here to enter numbers </button>

  <h3>List of Numbers </h3>

  <ul id="list"></ul>

  <div id="numbers"></div>

  <div id="floating"></div>

</form>
```

Comment: `number` is a string. Add `number = parseInt(number, 10)` after getting it. Better to do more sanity checks before just converting to a number.

Comment: I just tried it. I doesn't allow me to enter decimal numbers in the loop unfortunately.

Comment: Well, I was trying to give a direction. If you need floats, then `parseFloat`.

Comment: You can do like `number = +prompt` and it will cast your String to a number. If you are doing decimal Math in JavaScript you have to know that it won't come out like you might expect. In the end you might want a `number.toFixed(2)` solution.... and don't use `prompt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `parseInt` and `ParseFloat` functions in the function to get this working correctly. Also, you have to pass another `if` condition inside the while loop to prevent the "-1" from adding to the total. Hope the below code helps

```js
function examineNumbers() {

  const SENTINEL = -1;

  let number = 0;
  let type;
  let numValues = 0;
  let numAverage = 0;
  let floatValues = 0;
  let numTotal = 0;
  let floatTotal = 0;
  let list = document.getElementById("list");
  let numbers = document.getElementById("numbers");
  let floating = document.getElementById("floating");


  // while loop to only allow numbers greater than zero to be inputted
  while (number != SENTINEL) {
    number = prompt("Enter a number. Type " + SENTINEL + " to stop.");
    if (number == -1) {
      break;
    }
    // deterrmines if a number is even
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
      type = " is an even value";
      numTotal += parseInt(number);
      numValues++;
    }

    // determines if a number is odd
    else if (Math.abs(number % 2) == 1) {
      type = " is an odd value";
      numTotal += parseInt(number);
      numValues++;
    }

    // gives a floating point type if above two aren't met
    else {
      type = " is a floating point value.";
      floatTotal += parseFloat(number);
      numTotal += parseFloat(number);
      numValues++;
      floatValues++;
    }

    let numResults;
    let floatResults;
    // averages non floating numbers
    numAverage = numTotal / numValues;
    numResults = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " The total is " + numTotal.toFixed(2) +
      " and the average is " + numAverage + ".";

    // gives value if  no non floating numbers are entered
    if (numValues == 0 && floatValues == 0) {
      numResults = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
    }

    // averages floating point numbers
    floatAverage = floatTotal / floatValues;
    floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = " The total is " + floatTotal.toFixed(2) +
      " and the average is " + floatAverage + ".";


    // gives value if no floating numbers are entered
    if (floatValues == 0) {
      floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = "No floating-pont values were entered."
    }


    let li = "";
    //only add number and its status to list when number not equal to SENTINEL
    if (number !== SENTINEL) {
      li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = number + type;
      list.appendChild(li);

      // displays information for both non floating numbers and floating numbers
      numbers.innerHTML = numResults;
      floating.innerHTML = floatResults;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> Number Examination Tool </h1>

<form name="myForm">

  <button type="button" onclick="examineNumbers();">Click here to enter numbers </button>

  <h3>List of Numbers </h3>

  <ul id="list"></ul>

  <div id="numbers"></div>

  <div id="floating"></div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. One more question. Do you know where I would add ````toFixed(2)```` in the code? I tried where to add it after ````parseFloat(number)```` was added but that did not work.

Comment: Updated the code with `toFixed(2)`. Please check and approve this answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can learn something from the code below:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = function(node, className){
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
// magic under here - you can put code below on another page using a load event - except the `}); // end load`
const nums = I('nums'), calc = I('calc'), res = I('res'), evens_sum = I('evens_sum');
const evens_avg = I('evens_avg'), odds_sum = I('odds_sum'), odds_avg = I('odds_avg');
const int_sum = I('int_sum'), int_avg = I('int_avg'), dec_sum = I('dec_sum');
const dec_avg = I('dec_avg'), sum = I('sum'), avg = I('avg'), error = I('error');
function testNums(){
  for(let n of arguments){
    if(n === '' || isNaN(n)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
const calcNums = (()=>{
  const eve = [], odd = [], dec = [];
  let c, d, n;
  return ()=>{
    if(hC(error, 'hid')){
      c = d = 0; nums.value = nums.value.trim()
      eve.splice(0); odd.splice(0); dec.splice(0);
      const a = nums.value.split(/\s*,\s*/g);
      for(let s of a){
        n = +s;
        if(n % 1 !== 0){
          c = s.replace(/^.*\./, '').length; dec.push(n);
          if(c > d)d = c;
        }
        else if(n % 2 === 0){
          eve.push(n);
        }
        else{
          odd.push(n);
        }
      }
      let eL = eve.length, oL = odd.length, iL = eL+oL, dL = dec.length, tL = iL+dL;
      const eT = eve.reduce((a, v)=>a+v, 0), oT = odd.reduce((a, v)=>a+v, 0);
      const dT = dec.reduce((a, v)=>a+v, 0), iT = eT+oT, tT = iT+dT;
      evens_sum.textContent = eT; odds_sum.textContent = oT; int_sum.textContent = iT;
      dec_sum.textContent = dT.toFixed(d); sum.textContent = tT.toFixed(d);
      evens_avg.textContent = eL === 0 ? 0 : (eT/eL).toFixed(d);
      odds_avg.textContent = oL === 0 ? 0 : (oT/oL).toFixed(d);
      int_avg.textContent = iL === 0 ? 0 : (iT/iL).toFixed(d);
      dec_avg.textContent = dL === 0 ? 0 : (dT/dL).toFixed(d);
      avg.textContent = tL === 0 ? 0 : (tT/tL).toFixed(d);
      rC(res, 'hid');
    }
  }
})();
nums.oninput = function(){
  let v = this.value.trim();
  aC(res, 'hid');
  if(v.length && testNums(...v.split(/\s*,\s*/g))){
    f = aC;
  }
  else{
    f = rC;
  }
  f(this, 'yes'); f(error, 'hid');
}
calc.onclick = calcNums;
nums.onkeyup = e=>{
  if(e.key === 'Enter')calc.click();
}
}); // end load
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  padding:0; margin:0; font-size:0; border:0; box-sizing:border-box; outline:none;
  overflow:hidden; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.main{
  background:#aaa;
}
.bar{
  position:relative; width:100vw; height:39px; background:#ccc; color:#000; 
  padding:3px 3px 3px 7px; border-bottom:1px solid #333;
}
h1{
  font:bold 27px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.guts{
  width:100%; height:calc(100% - 39px); padding:5px 10px; overflow-y:auto;
}
.guts>*,.guts>#res *{
  font:bold 22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.guts>#res>div>span{
  color:#147;
}
label{
  color:#fff; text-shadow:-1px 0 #000,0 1px #000,1px 0 #000,0 -1px #000; margin-top:
}
label:first-child{
  margin-top:0;
}
input,textarea,select{
  width:100%; height:38px; background:#fff; color:#000; text-shadow:none; 
  border:1px solid #c00;
}
input,textarea{
  border-radius:3px; padding:5px;
}
input[type=button]{
  width:100%; height:auto; background:linear-gradient(#1b7bbb,#147); color:#fff;
  font:bold 28px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; padding:5px 10px; border:1px solid #007; 
  border-radius:5px; margin-top:7px; cursor:pointer;
}
.yes{
  border-color:#0c0;
}
#error{
  color:#900; font-size:18px; text-align:center;
}
.hid{
  display:none;
}
.bottom{
  width:100%; height:7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='bar'><h1>Number Fun</h1></div>
    <div class='guts'>
      <label for='nums'>Enter Comma Separated Numbers</label><input id='nums' type='text' value='' />
      <input id='calc' type='button' value='CALCULATE' />
      <div class='hid' id='res'>
        <div>evens sum: <span id='evens_sum'></span></div>
        <div>evens average: <span id='evens_avg'></span></div>
        <div>odds sum: <span id='odds_sum'></span></div>
        <div>odds average: <span id='odds_avg'></span></div>
        <div>integer sum: <span id='int_sum'></span></div>  
        <div>integer average: <span id='int_avg'></span></div>
        <div>decimal sum: <span id='dec_sum'></span></div>
        <div>decimals average: <span id='dec_avg'></span></div>
        <div>sum: <span id='sum'></span></div>
        <div>average: <span id='avg'></span></div>
      </div>
      <div id='error'>Comma Separated Numbers Only</div>
      <div class='bottom'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```